# error in npm installing angularfire2 and firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm-install, angularfire2, grpc

I was trying to install angularfire2 and firebase with npm like this

```
$ npm install angularfire2 firebase --save
```

The problem I am getting is

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\\Users\\New\\Documents\\academy\\academy\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\New\\Documents\\academy\\academy\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\New\Documents\academy\academy\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\New\Documents\academy\academy\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\New\Documents\academy\academy\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\New\Documents\academy\academy\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\New\\Documents\\academy\\academy\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\New\Documents\academy\academy\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\New\Documents\academy\academy\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\New\Documents\academy\academy\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown' (1)
npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.12.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.10.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`ild --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.10.1 install script.                  ditional logging output above.npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:                T15_46_21_982Z-debug.log
npm ERR!     C:\Users\New\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-03T15_46_21_982Z-debug.log
```

I have looked at the documentation and there [was a post that mentioned something about the version of `grpc@1.10.1` not being good](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/11239)  . I don't know if it was related to my specific problem I am using angular 5 and node 8.10 my version of npm is 5.6.0 any knowledge on problems here would be greatly appreciated. For people having a similar problem [I am also looking into using a cdn for firebase](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/angularfire2) (haven't fully done my research on it so don't take my word for it).

Comment: Can you look at the npm log file mentioned in that error and show is the first block of lines that start with "node-pre-gyp" and mention "grpc"? I think there may be relevant information there.

Comment: for some odd reason it started working I have no Idea why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely you will see this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gyp-mac-tool", line 611, in 
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "./gyp-mac-tool", line 28, in main
    exit_code = executor.Dispatch(args)
  File "./gyp-mac-tool", line 43, in Dispatch
    return getattr(self, method)(*args[1:])
  File "./gyp-mac-tool", line 246, in ExecFilterLibtool
    if not libtool_re.match(line) and not libtool_re5.match(line):
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

That is a python error. Make sure you have python 2.7 on your path and not 3.x as this tool doesn't support 3.x.

Comment: This might be the reason it started to work suddenly thanks I looked further into gyp you are actually supposed to run a command before to load the dependencies for gyp in an admin role. I did this and this could be the reason why it suddenly started to work.

Answer (score 3):

Use this command

```
npm install angularfire2  firebase@4.6.2 --save
```